# what's the difference in the codes?

Tags: java

I have written a java code of quicksort, and after debugging it many times, I decided to write a fresh new code of quicksort which is then implemented successfully.but when I compared my new code to the previous one I can't find any reason why it is not compiling. I know you can directly sort an array using `Arrays.sort(a);`
Here are the two codes

```
public static int partion(int[] a,int start,int end)
    {
        //Previous Code(buggy)
        /*int pivot =a[end];
        int pindex=start;
        for(int i=0;i<end;i++)
        {
            if(pivot>=a[i])
            {
                int s=a[i];
                a[i]=a[pindex];
                a[pindex]=s;
                pindex++;
            }
        }
        int j=pivot;
        pivot=a[pindex];
        a[pindex]=j;
        return pindex;*/

        //corrected one
        int pindex,pivot,swap,i;
        pivot=a[end];
        pindex=start;
        for(i=start;i<end;i++)
        {
            if(a[i]<=pivot)
            {
                swap=a[i];
                a[i]=a[pindex];
                a[pindex]=swap;
                pindex++;
            }
        }
        swap=a[pindex];
        a[pindex]=a[end];
        a[end]=swap;
        return pindex;
    }
```

please help as I am new to Java.
**EDIT** error is `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5`

Comment: If it doesn't compile, showing us the compiler error would certainly help.

Comment: `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is a runtime exception. It would not be found at compilation time. you need to debug to find the problem. which line throws the exception? this `pivot=a[end]` might be a problem if a has length 4 and end=4

Comment: That is not a compilation error but a logic bug. Which line in your code throws this error? What are the values of the variables at this point? Try to debug your code.

Comment: here's the link to entire code

Comment: https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/aIW8mtBEhj

Comment: the code (from the link) seems to work fine...

Answer (score 1):

The first difference is, that `>=` as it is in your bugged code is not the opposite of `<=`. You get the `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` because your check `>=` enables it when the smallest element becomes the pivot. The opposite allows the program to go exactly to the end of the index, while the bugged version will allow it to move one additional times.

Your second problem is after the for loop in the bugged code. If you only fix the upper bug, your result will be 11111. This is because of the line:

```
pivot=a[pindex];
```

Here you update a local int value, not the value in the array, hence you swap a value correctly into the other, but vice versa you just update your local variable, not the reference in the array as you do in the correct code:

```
a[end]=swap;
```

The fix for this is:

```
a[end]=a[pindex];
```